# jekyll breadcrumbs on github page has decoding error

Tags: github, jekyll, breadcrumbs, jekyll-theme

I'm app developer in Korea,
I have some problem at Github page with Jekyll.

https://sangh518.github.io/%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8/%EA%B8%B0%EB%A1%9D/Jekyll-serve-at-window/

This is which problem occurred page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCSMu.png)

When you see the page, you could see the url decoding, which worte in Korean is perfectly work, but at breadcrumbs category, decoding dosen't work.
I don't know how to fix it.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, are the breadcrumbs in an `_include` file or you're using a specific plugin? I think the issue is with non-ascii characters and maybe I can help depending on your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your ***_includes/breadcrumbs.html***, change

```
{{ crumb | replace: '-', ' ' | replace: '%20', ' ' | capitalize }}
```

to

```
{{ crumb | url_decode | replace: '-', ' ' | capitalize }}
```